# Mount Drive Unplugged, Folder Still Writable

Tags: mount

I created a folder using `sudo mkdir /mnt/external/` and then mount an external hdd to it:

```
$ mount -t ext2 /dev/sdd1 /mnt/external
```

I have an application writing backups to that mounted drive. Then, for fail test I simply unplug the external drive but the the application still keeps writing backups to that folder.

This is a problem because `/mnt/external/` folder now becomes a regular folder on the regular hard drive and the application fills up the actual hard drive which is running the OS.

How can I make sure that the application only writes to the mount point if the drive is currently mounted there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the drive unmounted,

```
$ sudo chmod a-rwx /mnt/external
```

A directory doesn't need to be readable or writable to have a filesystem mounted there.  When the filesystem is mounted, the permissions of `/mnt/external` come from the root directory of that filesystem.  When no filesystem is mounted there, they come from the filesystem containing `/mnt` (probably the system's root filesystem).

Comment: I have just tested that and confirmed that it works as you suggested. Setting the permissions a-rwx on that folder stopped the backups being written there. Thank you.

Comment: To clarify, you should remove any existing files from /mnt/external before the `chmod`.  Otherwise, they'll still be there, inaccessible but taking up space.

Comment: yeap i certainly did that.